# How to check if MongoDB error?

Tags: php, mongodb, error-handling

How can I check to see if there was an error with MongoDB?

```
var_dump($mongodb->lastError());
```

gives me a blank page.

Comment: Use "getLastError", not just "lastError".

Comment: Are you using `echo` or `var_dump`?  Can we see your full code?

Comment: var_dump($mongodb->lastError())

Comment: If you want to learn about the blank page you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Mongo::lastError](http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/en/mongo.lasterror.php)** — Check if there was an error on the most recent db operation performed

> **Deprecated**

```
// NOT WORK!!
$mongo = new Mongo();
var_dump($mongo->lastError());
```

You only see a **blank page** because you have error reporting turned `off` in your PHP configuration.

---

**[MongoDB::lastError](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.lasterror.php)** — Check if there was an error on the most recent db operation performed

> You need **MongoDB** class

```
// WORK!!
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db    = $mongo->database;
var_dump($db->lastError());
```

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1); i have message Function Mongo::lastError() is deprecated

Comment: $mongo = new Mongo();
$db    = $mongo->database;
var_dump($mongo->lastError());

Comment: `$mongo->lastError()` --> `$db->lastError()`

Comment: Thank you :) it works array(4) {
  ["n"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connectionId"]=>
  int(4)
  ["err"]=>
  NULL
  ["ok"]=>
  float(1)
}